# Java TCP options

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

C/Linux has the following...

> TCP_KEEPCNT (since Linux 2.4)
>                 The  maximum  number of keepalive probes TCP should send
>   before dropping the con-
>                 nection.  This option should not be used in code intended to
>   be portable.
>
> ```
>    TCP_KEEPIDLE (since Linux 2.4)
>           The time (in seconds) the connection needs to remain idle
> ```
>
> before TCP starts send-
>                 ing  keepalive  probes,  if  the  socket option SO_KEEPALIVE
>   has been set on this
>                 socket.  This option should not be used in code intended to
>   be portable.
>
> ```
>    TCP_KEEPINTVL (since Linux 2.4)
>           The time (in seconds) between individual keepalive probes.
> ```
>
> This  option  should
>                 not be used in code intended to be portable.

I know there are portability issues with these but is there anyway to alter these in Java on a Socket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set socket option (TCP\_KEEPCNT, TCP\_KEEPIDLE, TCP\_KEEPINTVL) in java or netty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472844/how-to-set-socket-option-tcp-keepcnt-tcp-keepidle-tcp-keepintvl-in-java-or-n)

Comment: I've marked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472844/how-to-set-socket-option-tcp-keepcnt-tcp-keepidle-tcp-keepintvl-in-java-or-n/29062476#29062476 as a duplicate of this (rather than vice versa) as (though I say it myself having written it) the former question has the fuller answer, and some useful other comments on JNA etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesn't look like something you can readily change from Java, a JNA/JNI wrapper around the C api probably your safest bet.