# How to set socket option (TCP_KEEPCNT, TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL) in java or netty?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, netty

In C/Linux, it's easily to set different value about those socket options for every **KEEPALIVE** tcp connection **independently**.

> TCP_KEEPCNT (since Linux 2.4)
>       The maximum number of keepalive probes TCP should send before dropping the connection.  This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.
>
> TCP_KEEPIDLE (since Linux 2.4)
>       The  time  (in seconds) the connection needs to remain idle before TCP starts sending keepalive probes, if the socket option SO_KEEPALIVE has been set on this socket.
>       This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.
>
> TCP_KEEPINTVL (since Linux 2.4)
>       The time (in seconds) between individual keepalive probes.  This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

In netty or java, how to set the three socket options for socket? I know there is no portable way to solve it, but only in Linux, can I set those socket options?

Comment: As mentioned in your documentation above, these options "[...]should not be used in code intended to be portable". You'd need to use JNI (or better, JNA) and implement your own `Socket`/`SocketFactory` if you want to use these

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161437/setsockopt-in-java-programs

Comment: Thanks all. It's need to use JNA to implement it.

Comment: For C++, it's described in this post: [Socket keepalive not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21867895/514235).

Answer (score 4):

The link given doesn't actually tell you *how* to use JNA to implement it. Having spent a while digging around on SO to find solutions, I wrote my own library. You can find it [here](https://github.com/abligh/jnasockopt).

Answer (score 4):

It appears this is supported in Java 11, via [new fields in the `ExtendedSocketOptions` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.net/jdk/net/ExtendedSocketOptions.html#TCP_KEEPIDLE). These can be passed to the `setOption` method on either `java.net.Socket` or `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel`.

Note I have not actually tried using this. The docs explicitly say these are platform specific, so you'll need to test they actually do what you want on the platforms you care about.

```java
import java.net.Socket;
import jdk.net.ExtendedSocketOptions;

Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 10);
socket.setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPCOUNT, 2);
socket.setOption(ExtendedSocketOptions.TCP_KEEPINTERVAL, 3);
```

Comment: Apparently this was also backported to some Java 8 distributions during 2020 for certain platforms like Linux and Mac OS. Source: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194298 and
https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2020-October/012817.html

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Netty allow you to use epoll type channels and set Linux-native socket options such as the ones you mentioned.

See the [documentation of EpollChannelOption](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollChannelOption.html) for details.